# String class split funtion is returning abigious results

Tags: java, regex

below are 2 codes

```
System.out.println(",,,,,".split(",").length);
```

and

```
System.out.println(",,,,, ".split(",").length);
```

for first code the result it prints is **0** and for the second code result it prints is 6.

My question is why the split is not able to recognize **","** when I am not adding extra space at the end but it is able to recognize it when I add extra space at the end.

Please note I have tried it with regex **"\\s*,\\s"** also but result is same.

Comment: @PaulRooney yup that was a typo thanks I have edited the question

Comment: if ",,,,," is void how ",,,, " is working, logically it should return string array with empty strings like ""

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a doc reference for this, but empirically what I saw in my testing of `String#split` is that if there are no actual text matches, then zero-width matches are also not returned in the array.  So the following returns an empty array:

```
",,,,,".split(",")
```

However, if you add a space to the end of the series of commas and then do the same split, then there is a single matching space.  As a result of this, the array comes back with all matches, including zero-width matches:

```
",,,,, ".split(",")
```

But, because there is no content in between the commas, I would interpret your real requirement as wanting to split each individual comma into a separate result.  If so, then you can split using lookarounds, something like this:

```
String input = ",,,,,";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=,)(?=,)");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

This outputs:

```
,
,
,
,
,
```

### Demo

Comment: maybe you can add in the return description of [`.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) documentation: "_the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression_"

Comment: using this regex it dont consider the last comma, for example for string ",,"length of array should be 3 but it is showing 2

Comment: @KushagraMisra It is somewhat unclear what the OP wants as output at the moment, because splitting on comma would basically remove everything from the input string.  I'll wait for feedback from the OP.

Comment: I was just curious why it is able to split string properly when an extra space available but not when there is no space

Comment: @KushagraMisra I don't have a doc reference for this, but it appears to be the case that if no actual text is matched, then the array returned is empty.  When you added a space, you forced an actual match, and therefore the array came back with every _match_ (not that every match actual had a width).

Answer (score 1):

`split()` in java by default removes trailing empty strings from result array. To keep empty, you can use `split(delimiter, limit)` with `limit` set to negative value, like this

```
System.out.println(",,,,," .split(",", -1).length);
```

Comment: More info : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: thanks pajri, it is showing the correct response, but still not clear how it was considering empty string if any one value is space

Answer (score 0):

Let's explore more see the interesting results of split below:

```
System.out.println(",,,,,,".split(",").length); // 0
System.out.println(",,,,,, ".split(",").length); // 7
System.out.println(",,, ,,,".split(",").length); // 4
System.out.println(" ,,,,,,".split(",").length); // 1
```

Wondering if why it's happening this is because below statement stated for the split method in docs:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

if you don't want the split method to remove that spaces then you should use another split with limit:

```
public String[] split(String regex,int limit)
```

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Example:

```
System.out.println(",,,,,,".split(",",-1).length); // 7
System.out.println(",,,,,, ".split(",",-1).length); // 7
System.out.println(",,, ,,,".split(",",-1).length); // 7
System.out.println(" ,,,,,,".split(",",-1).length); // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget documentation, I directly looked into the code and found the following piece of code in `java.lang.String#split(java.lang.String, int)`:-

```
while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize - 1).length() == 0) {
    resultSize--;
}
```

This proves that **it is designed to remove the last element if it is empty**. And keep doing it until the last element is not zero-length.

This feature is useful, for example, if you have a string `a,b,` it should return `a` and `b` in the resulting array and not the last blank character `''` after the last comma.

If you do `System.out.println(", ,,,".split(",").length);` it will return `2` because the above while loop will keep decreasing the result from the right side until it finds something whose length is non-zero.

The above while loop is enclosed in `if (limit == 0)`. So if you want to count all, use a non-zero limit. If you don't want any limit, use a negative number like -1.