# I am reading the text file (comma as a delimiter)from java

Tags: java, oracle

Sample Data file

```
INV1,A,BB,,,,
INV2,A,CC,,,,
INV3,C,BB,,,,
```

array getting only INV1 A and BB for first line, similarly INV2 a and CC for second and INV3 C and BB for third line. Remaining values are not considering.

My Code

```
        BufferdReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(/home/test.txt));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bReader.readLine ()) !=null)
    {
 if (line != null)
{
 String[] array = line.split(",") ;
  for (String arrays : array ) {
                System.out.println(arrays );
            }
}
}
```

OUT PUT :

```
INV1
A
BB
INV2
A
CC
INV3
C
BB
```

Expected OUT PUT

```
INV1
A
BB



INV2
A
CC



INV3
C
BB
```

Comment: Remaining values - what values? Can you explain what the question is please

Comment: Remaining values are blank ..

Comment: Will update the question

Comment: You should update the title as well to actually explain your question or problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with the split function of the String class.
This line should do the trick.

```
"INV1,A,BB,,,,".split(",", -1);
```

This answer explains it well enough: [String split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values).

Answer (score 2):

Add a limit to the split method:

```
String[] array = line.split(",", -1);
```

This is because the empty strings from the right are trimmed if you don't provide a limit. This behaviour is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835974/1039555).